# Overview of the mathematical (and computer science) world by countries

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, reference-request, ranking, statistics

I am looking for statistics of research done in mathematics and computer science by country. I found reports for [Thainland](http://www.mathunion.org/Publications/CircularLetters/Thailand-Evidence.pdf), [Kyrgyzstan](http://imuweb.mathunion.org/Publications/CircularLetters/KyrgyzstanEvidence.pdf) and [Finland](http://imuweb.mathunion.org/Publications/CircularLetters/Finland_Evidence.pdf) in mathematics. Where can I find similar statistics for other countries, and also the "bigger" ones like USA, Russia, UK, France, Germany etc.

Things that should be mentioned are: Major universities/institutes, what was achieved in the last decades, research output, people, topics and conferences held and a general overview. So how to find such information?

Comment: "conferences held" - Thailand is a pretty and interesting place, and thus quite suitable as a location for international conferences. Not sure how directly that attractiveness counts as "research done" ;)

Comment: At least in computer science conferences are mostly organized by a local research group in the field, so it has a link to the research done.

Comment: Let's just say ... there's a reason why the annual [HICSS conference](https://hicss.hawaii.edu/) takes place on Hawaii, and it's not exclusively because the local research groups are particularly prolific in the topics covered by the conference, compared to research groups at other places. Of course, there need to be local research groups interested in (co-)organizing the conference, but they're certainly not the only reason (and not even necessarily the most important one) for the selection of a location.

Comment: Okay, I agree; then conferences might not reflect the research done or might not count as an evaluation thereof, anyway would be good to have an overview, as conferences in some sense show whats going on.

Comment: Sure. Even though I am generally suspicious of seemingly one-dimensional rankings for complex things such as "research", I agree this comparison can be interesting in some respects; my comment about conference locations was a bit tongue-in-cheek, anyway.

Comment: Never said they are meant for some kind of ranking. If in country A where published just 1 article in a year, and country B maybe 100 articles I never meant to imply that country B might be ranked higher, as the content of the one article might be highly interesting (btw is it not clear how to compress all these factors mentioned into a single ranking). Just to have an overview, where, how and what, and in what intensity, is done in the countries. Pure numbers and facts, what anyone might derive from them is up to them.